# TOC generator for CSS - comments and documentation related issue

Tags: css, documentation, comments, sections

I'd like to improve my CSS inline comments and documentation.

I'm looking for a generator that will eat CSS input like:

```
/* @section 1.0 Foobar *

.foobar {
     color: #fff; }

/* @section 1.1 Hello *


... css definitions ...


/* Another sub comment *

... css definition ...

/* @section 1.2 Woop *
```

to output a section overview like:

```
  1.0 Foobar

     1.1 Hello

        1.1.1 Another sub comment

     1.2 Woop
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this covers what you're looking for, but try this http://csscomb.com/

Comment: No, I'm not looking for a sorting tool.